# How to mutate multiple SWR keys

Tags: reactjs, swr

I'm using SWR to show a paginated component, very similar to the [example in the docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination#pagination). My key looks something like

```
useSWR(`/api/items?offset=${offset}`)
```

I would like to upload a new list of items, and I want to tell SWR to revalidate all items requests since they will no longer be valid. I'm assuming `mutate` is still the right avenue to do this, but is there a way that I can tell mutate to invalidate many keys at once? Or ever better, all keys that match `/api/items(.*)`?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/761) for matching mutation keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SWR 2 or more, You can do something like this:

```js
import { mutate } from 'swr'
// Or from the hook if you customized the cache provider:
// { mutate } = useSWRConfig()

mutate(
  key => typeof key === 'string' && key.startsWith('/api/items?offset')
)
```

Comment: Docs for this: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#mutate-multiple-items